# how to make my own facebook class

Tags: php, facebook, class

i want to make my own class to make my code useful and easy.
i want to replace (for example)

```
$facebook->api('/me');
```

to

```
$myclass->me();
```

to post on wall for example i need to write

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed','post',$atch);
```

i want to make it

```
$myclass->msg($msg);
```

how can i make my own class using facebook class (and i using another DB class)

thanks for halp

Comment: This is basic PHP. Please read about classes and objects in PHP (and in general programming) and ask a more specific question should you have difficulties.

Comment: I feel its a meaningful question especially for some one very new to Stackoverflow, please do not discourage them by doing a -1 immediately. Instead help them frame better questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option #1** - quick, easy, common practice for OOP

```
class myFacebook extends facebook {
  public function me() {
    return $this->api('/me');
  }
  public function msg($msg) {
    return $this->api('/me/feed','post',$msg);
  }
}
```

**Option #2 (alternative)** - easyier to maintance, won't collide with base class properties, easy to extend. It's like API for API :)

```
class myFacebook {
  public $api;
  public function __construct() {
    $this->api = new facebook(); // your base class
  }
  public function me() {
    return $this->api->api('/me');
  }
  public function msg($msg) {
    return $this->api->api('/me/feed','post',$msg);
  }
  public function api() {
    // more difficult to declare that function in #1 option
  }
}
```

2nd option is better when your class uses lot of keywords and may collide with base API class. Easyier to maintance, easier to extend.

---

**I used to work with many API's (ebay,paypal,amazon,fb etc).**
I usually create 2-3 classes:

1. First one is just to sending and downloading data. For example SOAP class with caching.
2. Second class is creating proper requests, and using 1. class.
3. The most simplified one (like yours) - just having easy, and quick shortcuts to request class (which is your base class)

I know using `extend` the is most common practice, but personaly I preffer option #2.