# Alternative to Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I've been using for my latest project Twitter Bootstrap, but I've found to have compatibility issues with older browsers.

Now I want to start a new project and I don't want to use Bootstrap anymore. Do you know any alternative to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Kickstrap](http://ajkochanowicz.github.com/Kickstrap/) which is nice alternative to twitter-bootstrap.
But I would stay with twitter-bootstrap.

Comment: Good suggestion but that site uses words like "decent", "badass" and "mother effin" to take seriously.

Comment: if his project is having compatibility issues with Bootstrap, an extended version of Bootstrap is unlikely to solve his problems.

Comment: @con - [poor man's instant messaging]... I hope you were not offended by my comments on [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265864/how-to-make-my-own-facebook-class/12265918#12265918)... The idea of this site is to create a collection of useful Q&A posts that will be able to help visitors in the future.  An answer (even if it's correct) that depends solely on a link is prone to [link rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) and if the URL dies, the answer will have lost it's worth.  It's always better to provide an answer that can stand alone and provide a link for reference.

Comment: @Lix: :) 
Shalom leha. First of all, your GIF on [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix) page is a genius, I actually started to write there :)
shenit, of course I'm not offended, you were right and I even marked your comment "helpful". IMHO the problem there was with the question, if it would be good question then I would put more energy & time to write useful answer. Your comment was on the place!
hakol le tova :)